# I'm reordering some CSS elements, but certain properties seem to be going ignored

Tags: html, css

I started copying elements and reordering the style elements, I found out that some elements are simply not being computed into the HTML (even though I haven't changed any of the code). It should show as a button inside a flexbox, but it's not displaying properly now on my latest version. Do you mind looking at the code and helping me find out why it's not adequately displaying most of the text attributes I assigned to it?

```css
#flexIV {
    width: 404px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

#BTT_1 a {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: yellow;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: crimson;
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#BTT_1 {
    /*background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);*/
    width: 134.6px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;    
}
```

```html
<div id="flexIV">
    <div id="BTT_1">
        <!-- <div id="check">-->
            <a href="#">Check<br>webpage</a>
        <!--</div>-->
    </div>
</div>
</div> <!-- if I delete this element the next property disappears -->
```

The text in the  element is just showing as a clickable link.

Comment: What is the ... and the */ following it for? Looks like they are left over from some test. Use you browser dev tools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being picked up and put your code through a validator.

Comment: Thank you for your quaestion! The /* */ tags are for comments in the code and the ... is replacing some irrelevant elements (in this case, it's an element I've added at the end of my flexbox. Please let me know if you have any more questions about my post :)

Comment: refresh this page, and click on the run code snippet button and check if the result shown is what you want?

Comment: @Flappyfluff my question was not about the well formed CSS comment, but about the stray */ in your code which now seems to have gone. Does your code now pass validation tests?

Answer (score 0):

Your link isn't working so I can't check your example, however, as your CSS is currently written, everything below this line won't compute:

```
*/
/*Enter-BTT*/
}
```

As this is an open/improperly written comment. Try deleting that line and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: Hi fellow contributor, thank you so much for your answer. I believe there was a misunderstatement above: the link is just a bogus link so just to demonstrate how the button is showing. It seems that I've made a typo though... I've now edited the post, since that */ comment tag is part of something I've partially hid in a comment section :) PS I'm using Sublime Text and no error is currently being shown with it so far... However I'm testing two different browsers so far and the two versions of that button continue to display differently :/